# Firefox - Images disappear on scroll or don't render

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Against my best wishes I've created a site that makes use of parallax. While everything is looking good on Chrome and Safari, Firefox is throwing a wrench in things.

The site can be found here:
http://pm-devtest.herokuapp.com/

Attempt scrolling down the page in Firefox. Images disappear at random times, just before they reach the top of the screen, and some things don't even render at all. If you want to see the difference then feel free to view it in Chrome.

While you all are probably going to comment at me to post relevant code, this is difficult given the structure of the project and how the error revolves around the image rendering. I created a really rough pen [here](http://codepen.io/bscheibe/pen/EVGNZJ) that pulls in all the CSS on the page. However it doesn't have the images so it doesn't show much.

Specifically it has something to do with the parallax CSS (of course...) which I'll post here.

```
.parallax {
  height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  .perspective(300px);
}

.parallax__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
  height: 100vh;
  .transform-style(preserve-3d);

  &#group1 {
    // height: 700px;
  }

  &#group2 {
    margin-bottom: 5400px;
    // height: 1350px;
  }

  &#group3 {
    margin-bottom: 1700px;
    // height: 1100px;
  }

  &#group4 {
    margin-bottom: 3000px;
  }

  &#group5 {
    margin-bottom: 2400px;
    // height: 1200px;
  }

  &#group6 {
    margin-bottom: 5400px;
  }

  &#group7 {
    margin-bottom: 1500px;
    // height: 1100px;
  }

  &#group8 {
    margin-bottom: 2400px;
  }

  &#group9 {
    margin-bottom: 1350px;
    // height: 1350px;
  }

  &#group10 {
    margin-bottom: 3200px;
  }

  &#group3half {
    height: 100px;
    height: 1vh;
  }

  .quote1 {
    margin-top: 1150px;
  }

  .quote2 {
    margin-top: 750px;
  }

  .roots {
    margin-top: 1000px;
  }

  &.small {
    height: 250px; /* fallback for older browsers */
    height: 25vh;
  }

  &.slow-img {
    height: 20px;
    height: 1vh;
    text-align: center;
  }

  &.xsmall-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 300px;
  }

  &.small-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 800px;
  }

  &.small-medium-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 1100px;
  }

  &.spacer {
    margin-bottom: 1600px;
  }

  &.medium-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 2400px;
  }

  &.large-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 3200px;
  }

  &.xlarge-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 4000px;
  }

  &.xxlarge-spacer {
    margin-bottom: 5300px;
  }
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__layer--fore {
  .transform(translateZ(90px) scale(.7));
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax__layer--before {
  .transform(translateZ(-100px) scale(1.2));
  z-index: 1;
}

.parallax__layer--base {
  .transform(translateZ(0));
  z-index: 4;
}

.parallax__layer--back {
  .transform(translateZ(-300px) scale(2));
  z-index: 3;
}

.parallax__layer--deep {
  .transform(translateZ(-600px) scale(3));
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__layer--deep-back {
  .transform(translateZ(-450px) scale(2.5));
  z-index: 2;
}


/* demo styles
--------------------------------------------- */

.parallax {
  font-size: 200%;
}

 /* centre the content in the parallax layers */
.title {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  .transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
}

/* style the groups
--------------------------------------------- */

div[id^="group"] {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

#group1 {
  z-index: 5; /* slide over group 2 */
}
#group1half {
  z-index: 6;
}
#group2 {
  z-index: 3; /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
}
#group3 {
  z-index: 4; /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
}
#group3half {
  z-index: 6;
}

#group4 {
  z-index: 2; /* slide under group 3 and 5 */
}
#group5 {
  z-index: 3; /* slide over group 4 and 6 */
}
#group6 {
  z-index: 2; /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
}
#group7 {
  z-index: 3; /* slide over group 7 */
}
```

Honestly I'm at my wits end and just trying to see if anybody can come up with why this may be happening. I've cleared my cache so it's not a caching issue.

Comment: I wonder if those margins, being enormous, are more than Firefox can handle.

Comment: Yah I figured that might be the case. Good to hear it from someone else.

Comment: Having the same issue! See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146084/css-parallax-working-beautifully-in-chrome-but-not-firefox#